# jQuery - get AJAX response headers

Tags: jquery, httpresponse

How do we get access to the response headers when we fire an ajax request using jQuery? I tried with the below code as per the suggestions given in some sites. But `xhr` object is coming as null. I see an `xhr` object in this context. But it doesn't have methods to access response headers.

```js
function SampleMethod() {
  var savedThis = this;
  this.invokeProcedure = function(procedurePath) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: procedurePath,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data,status,xhr) savedThis.resultSetHandler(data,status,xhr);}
    });
  }

  this.resultSetHandler=function(data,status,xhrObj){
    //Handle the result
  }

  this.errorHandler = function(args) {
    //Handle the result
  }

}

var sampleObj = new SampleMethod();
sampleObj.invokeProcedure('url');
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

> For backward compatibility with XMLHttpRequest, a jqXHR object will
>   expose the following properties and methods: *getAllResponseHeaders()*
>   and
>   *getResponseHeader()*.
>   From the $.ajax() doc : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

For jQuery > 1.3

```
success: function(res, status, xhr) { 
  alert(xhr.getResponseHeader("myHeader"));
}
```

Comment: getAllResponseHeaders() gives only
 
    content-length: 0
    content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

but in Chrome Network I see 

    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: fa...
    ...
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sho...
    Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728...
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 0
    Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UT
    Refresh: 0; url=https://sec...
    Server: nginx/1.1...
    Set-Cookie: lang=ru; ...

fnd more. I need Refresh but can't get it

Comment: Same as above comment, doesn't work, only content-type and content length is available

Answer (score 4):

**FOR JQUERY 3 AND LATER**

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```js
//I only created this function as I am making many ajax calls with different urls and appending the result to different divs
function makeAjaxCall(requestType, urlTo, resultAreaId){
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    type: requestType,
    url: urlTo
  });

  //this section is executed when the server responds with no error 
  jqxhr.done(function(){
  });

  //this section is executed when the server responds with error
  jqxhr.fail(function(){
  });

  //this section is always executed
  jqxhr.always(function(){
    //here is how to access the response header
    console.log("getting header " + jqxhr.getResponseHeader('testHeader'));
  });
}
```