# How to get Response headers in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following code for an AJAX call

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://******/cxf/view/*****",
        data: {*****},
        headers: {*****},
        success: function (dt, status, request) {
            console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders());

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status) {

        }
    });
```

This is printing only content-type. In the developer console i can see number of headers in  the response. How can i get those headers in AJAX

[image]

Comment: You can use 'dataType' in ajax setting. means you can change which type of data thats you want it like 'json, xml etc'

Comment: @softsdev what should i give in dataType ?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440918/jquery-get-ajax-response-headers?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: please refere http://stackoverflow.com/a/2722770/1719246

Comment: @ParthTrivedi already tried it gives null

Comment: Have to give `dataType`

Comment: @softsdev dataType handles specifies the data returned by server na. It has nothing to do with headers

Comment: @ParthTrivedi which dataType ?? tried with HTML and JSON same result

Comment: @softsdev its not loading

Comment: One also has to make sure that the server sets the response header `Allow-Access-Control-Headers` with the header you want to have access in your JavaScript, or else it will not be visible. See [doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) for more information

Answer (score 15):

It's seems no problem. I tried and got it works.

Use [JSONPlaceholder](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) and here is my code

```
$.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts/1',
  headers: {'test': 'test'},
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data, status, xhr) {
  console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
});
```

the result is

```
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Wed, 23 Dec 2015 06:36:57 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: Cowboy
X-Powered-By: Express
Vary: Origin
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Length: 292
Etag: W/"124-yv65LoT2uMHrpn06wNpAcQ"
Expires: -1
```

Comment: check my updated question. The response header is showing in Developer console.

Answer (score 9):

On your server you need to add

```
res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "header-you-want-to-expose");
```

and then you will be able to access it in the browser.

Comment: @ZachSmith Perhaps the downvoter took offence to the presumed server technology (node?), although in this case it can be easily transferred to any other - so it's not appropriate in my opinion.

Comment: Adding this header is the answer. Although OP doesn't specifally state it is a cross origin request, it is implied by the CORS headers shown in their screenshot. +1 from me.

Answer (score 5):

I used the **same** code you used

```
success: function (dt, status, request) {
            console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders());
```

Problem is not with Jquery or Ajax. Response headers are set by Server. The server you are sending the request to, is not setting the headers! Simple!!!!

When i tried with my server [Some responses blurred for security]
i got the following output

[image: Snap of Console output]

Comment: The how the developer console shows those headers ??

Comment: @AnoopLL You should set headers of a response when returning a response. If its OK can you show me the code of cfx/view ??

Comment: I have added an Image in my question. Actually we are using rest call and its cross domain. You can see response headers in that image, those headers are set from the server.