# How to get response headers from ajax post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, isomorphic-fetch-api

I want to retrieve response headers sent by server. But i am getting empty object. I can see response headers in chrome dev tools, but can't get them from javascript.

(I am using isomorphic-fetch lib for xhr requests.)

```
        fetch("http://my.cors.url/postsomedata", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(myjsobject),
        })
        .then(response => response.headers)
        .then((headers) => {
            console.log(headers); // empty object
        })
```

This is not dublicate of
[How to get Response headers in AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429628/how-to-get-response-headers-in-ajax)
I am not using jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Response headers in AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429628/how-to-get-response-headers-in-ajax)

Comment: If you can't get it from `response.headers`, you can't get it. This smells like a CORS problem.

Comment: @KevinB, but why i can see them in chrome dev tools ?

Comment: because those are the dev tools. There's a lot of things in the dev tools that you can't access/do from javascript.

Comment: perhaps it is related to this issue? https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/issues/97

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on my back-end server CORS configuration.
I am using spring boot, so in order do pass custom headers into xhr response i need to configure spring boot application in following way

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                    .exposedHeaders("MyHeader");
        }
    };
}
```